# Negative lookahead matches

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Text:

```
4.7.3.0/upgradeScript.sql
4.8.1.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.1.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.13.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.15.0/upgradeScript.sql
```

Need to match:

```
4.7.3.0
4.8.1.0
5.0.1.0
5.0.13.0
5.0.15.0
```

I tried using negative lookahead and it matches everything for some reason:

```
\S+(?!\/)
```

What do I need to change to achieve my goal?

Comment: [`\S+(?=\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/Gepg1T/1) will match `ABC/4.7.3.0` in `ABC/4.7.3.0/upgradeScript.sql`. See [the correct answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47395710/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find any contiguous non space chars that *are* followed by a `/`, so need positive look ahead

```
\S+(?=\/)


`\S+` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
  `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Positive Lookahead `(?=\/)`
  Assert that the Regex below matches
  `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
```

(Explanation taken from https://regex101.com/)

This matches

```
4.7.3.0
4.8.1.0
5.0.1.0
5.0.13.0
5.0.15.0
```

from

```
4.7.3.0/upgradeScript.sql
4.8.1.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.1.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.13.0/upgradeScript.sql
5.0.15.0/upgradeScript.sql
```

as required by the OP

Answer (score 0):

Your `\S+(?!\/)` pattern works like this: `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars as many as possible (up to the string/line end) and then checks for a `/`. As it is not there, the whole string/line is returned.

To match 1+ chars other than `_` at the start of the string you may use

```
^[^\/]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA45bD/1)